# Калькулятор на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать калькулятор с помощью jQuery. Я чуть-чуть по колдовал, и [вот, что у меня получилось](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/nLMGE/) (не получилось):):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\о

о/

Как вы складываете числа в уме? Сначала запоминаете первое число, потом ко второму числу прибавляете первое. Т.е. скрипт для каждой операции должен сохранять предпоследнее значение. Дальше обычные проверки идут.

```
$(function() {
    var lastNum = false;
    var lastOperator = '';
    calcScreen = $('#screen input');
    calcScreen[0].value = '0';

    //
    $('#number li a, #operators li a, #result').click(function() {
        /**
         * clear
         */
        if(this.text.toLowerCase() == 'c') {
            lastNum = 0;
            calcScreen.val(0);
            return;
        }

        /**
         * end
         */
        if(this.text.toLowerCase().trim()  == '=') {
            if(!lastNum) {
                calcScreen.val(calcScreen[0].value);
                return;
            }
            calcScreen.val(eval(String(lastNum) + String((/\w/.exec(calcScreen[0].value))?String(lastOperator) + calcScreen[0].value:'')));
            return;
        }

        /**
         * operators
         */
        if(/^\W/.exec(this.text)) {
            if(lastNum) {
                calcScreen.val(eval(String(lastNum) + String((/\w/.exec(calcScreen[0].value))?String(lastOperator) + calcScreen[0].value:'')));
            }

            lastNum = calcScreen.val();

            calcScreen.val(this.text);
            lastOperator = this.text;
            return;
        }

        /**
         * echo
         */
        if(calcScreen[0].value == '0' || (/^\W/.exec(calcScreen[0].value))) {
            calcScreen[0].value = this.text;        
        }
        else {
            calcScreen[0].value += this.text;       
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @lampa, а почему не выполняются операции с нецелыми числами?

    1,5 * 2 не работает...

Буду признателен если подскажите.

P.s. Если не сложно, не могли бы Вы дать комментарий к каждой строчке кода. Дело в том, что только начал изучать JS, и многое не понятно, а вникнуть и понять как - что работает, очень хочется.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: я не учел запятую. Скоро обновлю пост с комментированием.

Comment: @lampa, спасибо, буду ждать.

С уважением, Александр

P.s. только заметил, если выполняем несколько операций подряд, то выдает неверный результат...

Comment: простите, но что это такое:

    calcScreen.val(calcScreen[0].value);

?

а вообще тру решением было бы преобразовывать ввод в обратную польскую нотацию и проводить вычисления, а не `eval` использовать

Comment: @Spectre сам смеюсь :D про ОПН - калькулятор простой, я думаю этот метод будет лишним в данном случае.

Answer (score 1):

макет красивый, а вот функционала, который должен выполнять калькуляторные функции -- нет как такового.
начните с решения этой задачи на чистом джаваскрипт, жквери тут и не нужен особо.

Comment: @deivan, спасибо. JavaScript - это конечно здорово, но так как знаний по js чуть > 0, для меня это будет сложновато. Не могли бы Вы "пнуть" в нужном направлении (шаги реализации и т.д.).

Comment: Без знаний в JS не стоит браться за jQuery (как и за любой другой JS-фреймворк).
Обратите внимание на то, что люди не любят тратить много времени, и тыкать мышкой в кнопочки никому не интересно. Сделайте поддержку нажатий на клавиатуре.

Comment: @sorx00, полностью с Вами согласен, поэтому поэтому в настоящее время, активно изучаю JS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alex_xpert/3PQNJ/ Вот моё решение на чистом JS

Comment: @alex_xper, спасибо.
Вам +10

P.s. Такая же проблема как и в выше приведенном решении. Если выполняется несколько операций сразу, то выдает неверный результат...

Comment: [Alex83][1], исправил.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/8823/alex83

Comment: @alex_xper, ... ... не работает...

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/alex_xpert/3PQNJ/1/][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/alex_xpert/3PQNJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать глянуть в сторону [RightJS](http://ru.rightjs.org/). Там разобраться проще простого, есть примеры игр, например на ibm developerworks есть 2 статьи как написать сапер на RightJS:

- [Разработка игры "сапер" с помощью
     RightJS: Часть 1. Общие принципы](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-rightjs-part1/)
- [Разработка игры "сапер" с помощью
     RightJS: Часть 2. Логика
     приложения](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-rightjs-part2/)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Koval, Вы вообще читали вопрос, прежде чем дать ответ...? Думаю, что нет.